# rails refinerycms extend controller with decorator is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I am trying to extend user controller of refinerycms gem with in decorator method

Here is my code of decorator/controllers/refindery/user_controller_decorator.rb

```
Refinery::usersController.class_eval do

    before_filter :myfunc, :only => [:home,:new, :create, :sign_in, :sign_out ]

    def myfunc
        abort('this is it')
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean `Refinery::UsersController` (With capital "U")?

Comment: Yes I have changed from small u to capita "U", but still no luck

Comment: Also, the file should be in `app/decorators/controllers/refinery/users_controller_decorator.rb`

Comment: I have solved this by clearing tmp cache :)